# I'm trying to understand what the algorithm does

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to understand the algorithm .. i think this is the shortest route from p to q, but this is not always true
(p,q two nodes in a binary tree) ..thanks!

```
   c <- 0 
   while p ≠ q 
      if right[p] ≠ NULL 
         p <- right[p] 
         while left[p] ≠ NULL 
            p <- left[p] 
      else 
         if left[p] = NULL 
            c <- c + 1 
         while p = right[parent[p]] 
            p <- parent[p] 
         p <- parent[p] 
   return c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is counting the number of leaves between nodes p and q if you traversed the nodes in order by their values.

Comment: ,the algorithm work only if the tree is binary search tree or its doesnt matther?

Comment: "in order by their values" obviously won't work if it's not a *search* tree, and the code assumes it's *binary*. so what's the question?

Comment: It was tagged to be a BST.

Comment: ok...thank you Scott Hunter!

Answer (score 0):

It's counting how many bottom-level nodes there are in the tree (ie those that have neither right nor left children).  Notice that the 'c' is only incremented for nodes where this is true.

Comment: What if p=q initially?